# Performance issue: t-sql vs clr

Tags: sql-server, clr

I am just wondering which will be faster t-sql function/procedure or clr version of one?  A procedure works with database data and use cursors (t-sql version).

When should I use clr and when I should use t-sql to create procedures and functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple rule-of-thumb:

- **data manipulation** (SELECT, UPDATE etc.) are best left to T-SQL (but **without** cursors!)
- while anything that has to do with **processing** (string/regex matching, date arithmetic, calling external web services etc.) is a good match for SQL-CLR